# For linear maps $A, B : V \to V$, how to show rank$(A +B) \leq $ rank$(A) +$ rank$(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Other questions have asked this in a matrix context. I am interested in the same question for linear maps $A$ on a vector space $V$ such that $A:V \to V$. (I believe these are also called linear operators.)

If this question is ill-posed (eg, are such linear maps always matrices?), then i apologize in advance.

Perhaps a proof would involve the ranks of the images of A and B, rather than the ranks of A and B themselves?

Comment: Fixed a base of V, every linear map $V \to V$is represented by one and only one matrix. Therefore the standard proof for a matrix is sufficient.

Comment: @g What do you mean by "the ranks of the images"? A matrix has a rank, and a linear map has a rank, but the image of a transformation (which is a vector subspace) has a "dimension" but no "rank".

Comment: Thank you for correcting my misuse of terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in im(A+B)$. Then $x = (A+B)v$ for some $v\in V$. Taking this further leads to
$$x=(A+B)v = Av+Bv \in im(A)+im(B)$$
And therefore
$$im(A+B)\subseteq im(A)+im(B)\Rightarrow \underbrace{\dim(im}_{rank}(A+B))\leq \underbrace{\dim(im}_{rank}(A))+\underbrace{\dim(im}_{rank}(B))$$